# Scala Play convert a request to JSON and write it to MongoDB

Tags: scala, playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

I'm using Play 2.5 and ReactiveMongo. It's a simple problem but I can't figure it out. I have a controller that receives a `username` and `password` from a view, I want to convert this request to a model of type `UserModel` and then convert this model to json and write it to MongoDB.

My controller:

```
class RegisterController @Inject() (val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi) 
extends Controller with MongoController with ReactiveMongoComponents {

  def registerPost = Action.async { request =>

  implicit val accountWrites = new Writes[UserModel] {
  def writes(account: UserModel) = Json.obj(
    "username" -> account.username,
    "password" -> account.password
  )
} //needs this for some reason?

val future = collection.insert(request.body) //trying to insert to mongo
future.map(_ => Ok)
```

My model:

```
case class UserModel(username: String, password: String) {}

object UserModel {

  implicit val format = Json.format[UserModel] //needs this for some reason?

  val userModel = Form(
mapping(
  "username" -> nonEmptyText,
  "password" -> nonEmptyText
)(UserModel.apply)(UserModel.unapply))
}
```

My view:

```
@(userForm: Form[UserModel])(implicit messages: Messages)

<h1>Register</h1>

@helper.form(action = routes.RegisterController.registerPost()) {
  @helper.inputText(userForm("username"))
  @helper.inputText(userForm("password"))

  <button type="submit" name="action" value="register">Register</button>

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the key things you need to do:

=> `Bind the form request` in your controller method , `registerPost` . For this, you also need to have the `form mapping` settings. This mapping will help you to generate `UserModel` object using the form data inside the method. For doing all this, see here [ScalaForms](http://%60UserModel%60%20object%20using%20the%20form%20data%20inside%20the%20method)

=> You dont need `writes` here. You can use `format` to perform both `json writes and reads`.

=> Now convert the UserModel into JsValue as:

```
//usermodel will be generated by binding the form data
implicit val format = Json.format[UserModel]
val userModelJson = format.writes(usermodel)
```

=> Then you can simply call the repository as:

```
collection.insert(userModelJson)
```

Comment: There is no need to use form to get JSON body from a request

Comment: I never said `it is the only way` to get JSON body. You cannot do complex validations with `request.body` approach. I am trying to explain with my approach and how I handle these kind of use cases. If you find a mistake, point it out and if you have a different opinion, feel free to add an answer.

Comment: This has worked perfectly, thank you for your answer. I didn't know `format` could be used like that.

Comment: The `Reads` API also provides way to validate a parsed JSON body.